# Can ASP.Net Drop Down List Control Be Used to Navigate to Another Page in Same Site

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

For an outside of the box idea on a particular site I'm building, I would like to use a drop down list control, which has two inputs: Sponsor1 and Sponsor2. My goal is that when a visitor chooses one of the options, they will go a page for that particular sponsor, and enter a pre-defined code via a textbox w/ a "Next" button, which will take them to yet another page to enter more info.

I'm sort of dividing the site up to have branches, as the sponsors will have visitors (i.e., customers) and the sponsors can keep track of these visitors via the input that will go to a database yet to be made.

As I'm creating this in Asp.Net/C#, I cannot find any examples of this being done, outside an old reference being done with JavaScript - yet the end concept is not the same:

[Creating a drop-down list that links to other pages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lisawoll/archive/2004/08/19/217427.aspx?Redirected=true)

So is this possible to code something in C# within the code-behind to make this behave as I wish, or must I scrap this idea and just do it another way?  Thanks to all in advance!!

Comment: `autopostback=true` and then do a `response.redirect` or `server.transfer` in the code-behind

Comment: you can do it by using javascript or Jquery

Comment: I would like to accomplish it without using javascript, yet I'm new at asp.net, so I'm having a hard time knowing where to implement the example as shown previous in my code behind, via the OnInit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling an event when the user selects something on the drop-down list?

Edit: Added more context to where everything goes.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs)
{
  dropDownList.selectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlIndexChanged);
  base.OnInit(ea);
}

//Your Page_Load Here

private void ddlIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
  //This is called when the index is changed, you could redirect here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am confused as to where I need to write this. Will this come before the following:

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

or 

`protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

I don't where I'm supposed to be declaring this position-wise.

Comment: It would be best to put it before the Page_Load because it will be called before page load. Also because OnInit is overriding the base OnInit you will need to call the base OnInit so your code should look like this "Protected override void OnInit(EventArgs ea){ base.OnInit(); }" I'll write it above in code format so it will look clearer.